# Ubuntu on Mac cannot locate via OSX or boot it throught rEFIt...

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, macosx, refit

... it comes up with `Operating system not found`. **What do i do?**

---

I recently installed Ubuntu along side OS X (Snow Leopard) and when I rebooted my macbook and choose Ubuntu, I got a message saying `Operating system not found...`. I thought this maybe have something to do with **Grub**, so I've tried using the terminal from a live CD but it still isn't working, yet I can still access it through the live CD and see it installed, and there is a whole partition for it.
**What do i do to get it working?**

Comment: did you read this page ? [Booting Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a USB flash drive with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (download the USB flash drive version and write it to your USB drive as described in the documentation). When you boot from it, the flash drive *should* give you options to boot both OS X and Linux. If this works, install rEFInd *from OS X* from the binary `.zip` file, and be sure to install the EFI driver for the filesystem you used for Ubuntu (ext4fs by default).